# Xcode PhoneGap navigator.connection Undefined

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Trying to port my PhoneGap javascript code into Xcode for debugging in iOS.
Using Cordova-3.0.0.

When I call:

```
navigator.connection.type
```

I am getting an 'undefined' for navigator.connection.

Did I not include the network connection plugin correctly in my config.xml, or is something else amiss? Yes, I included the correct cordova.js file specifically for iOS.  Yes, deviceready has been fired.

Update: I am currently only running this on the iOS emulator.

My config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.app.test" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Hello Cordova</name>
    <description>
        Description
    </description>
    <author email="dev@callback.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <plugins>
        <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="CDVConnection" />
    </plugins>
</widget>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Any luck in solving this? I'm getting the same error on BlackBerry.

Comment: Yes, finally figured it out today.  See the solution below.  They updated the config settings for iOS, and it might have been updated for BlackBerry as well. Check the [PhoneGap API Documention for 3.0.0][http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection].

Comment: Cheers for that. Unfortunately I'm using cordova 2.5.0 and that's not my issue. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Been doing my research on this one, and finally came up with the solution.
Apparently PhoneGap (Adobe) recently updated their documentation, and filled in a lot of the holes I was running into for Phonegap 3.0.0

1) To do this using the command-line interface, you have to have git installed to be able to run those commands.  Get [git here](http://git-scm.com/downloads).

2) They added to the [Connection](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection) plugin documentation to use the following command-line interface commands to add the plugin to the project:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-network-information.git
$ cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.core.network-information
```

3) They updated the declaration in the config.xml file to the following (for iOS):

```
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVConnection" />
</feature>
```

Comment: Comment from **deavisdude** _The solution here didn't fix anything for me. In fact, I originally installed this version of the network info plugin and still got the undefined error. I have checked everything and been doing this for days... How did you get this to work and can you post a working example?_

Comment: @deavisdude This example is specific to a bug encountered in the first few days Cordova 3.0.0 was released, and the documentation was fixed shortly after.  The issue has been completely resolved in later versions of PhoneGap, which I have used successfully.  Later versions specify the add commands as (example): `cordova plugins add org.apache.cordova.network-information` and there is no need to manually edit the config.xml.  Which version of Cordova/Phonegap are you running?  This may warrant a new question post for you.  If you do, post link here and I can possibly help you through it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to know if you are connected or not try using navigator.onLine in your js instead. Works for me on IOS 8 & Android 2.3 and doesn't require any plugins

Comment: While that may be, you missed the point of the topic.  The thread is because navigator was undefined, and therefore you could not call navigator.onLine anyways.

Comment: Maybe I have missed the point, but as far as I can see the OP says "I am getting an 'undefined' for navigator.connection" not "I am getting an 'undefined' for navigator" so maybe navigator.onLine will work for them (or for other people with similar problems).

Comment: True, it's been so long since I first posted this question, that I can't remember if navigator was null (which I think it was) or if navigator.connection was null.  You're right about the wording of the OP, my apologies.  Maybe navigator.onLine will help someone.

Comment: @mike, thanks !!  navigator.onLine is defined and working, even without the plugin.  It is a much simpler solution, even more so since the stock plugin doesn't seem to work.