# phonegap navigator.connection is undefined

Tags: ios, cordova, connection, navigator

I've got a problem using `Phonegap`.
I've created a Test application using console:

```
phonegap create ProjectTest

cordova platform add ios

cordova build
```

Then opened generated Xcode project and added new line to onDeviceReady function:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    // MY TEST
    alert(navigator.connection);      
}
```

Also i've added this line to my config.xml:

```
<plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="CDVConnection" />
```

So, result in alert is 'undefined'......

I just need to test the connection, using `navigator.connection.type`

Using `MacBook` and `Xcode 4.6.3`

Comment: @MilenPavlov backticks are not for keywords/emphasis!

Comment: This appears to be a similar issue to what I'm experiencing, here is [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862136/xcode-phonegap-navigator-connection-undefined) from a few days ago with no answers.  I hope someone answers this soon!

Answer (score 3):

Same issue here. I was testing my code after these steps. create, add platform ios, add plugin blabla. When you do like this, **its not working.** You have to say

```
$ cordova build ios
```

or

```
$ phonegap build ios
```

after that, its creating new files about plugins and **its working**. Hope that help you too.

*(cordova 3.3.0)*

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue, and was able to answer my own question after a bunch of research.

See this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862136/xcode-phonegap-navigator-connection-undefined/18063464#18063464) for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should add connection [plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection) first