# Cordova 3 - iOs - navigator.connection Undefined

Tags: networking, plugins, cordova, connection

Hi I'm trying to access connection on iOs device without any success...

I try to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862136/xcode-phonegap-navigator-connection-undefined/18063464#18063464) withot any result.

I run:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-network-information.git
$ cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.core.network-information
```

and added:

```
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVConnection" />
</feature>
```

in the `config.xml` file. I also try to wrap the feature lines in a `<plugin></plugin>` tag as I was not sure if it was needed, but nothing.

If I run from CLI: `cordova plugin list`

I obtain as expected: `[ 'org.apache.cordova.network-information' ]`

But I keep on getting undefined if I try to alert the connection type (I checked that I'm waiting the deviceReady event). Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

first of all, why would you run `$ cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.core.network-information`? what this does is **removing** your plugin, right after you installed it. somehow, of course, according to `cordova plugin list` the plugin is installed anyway, so let's move on.

make sure all plugin files are in the right spot. cordova 3 has the habit to not copy the **native** plugin files into the platform folder. you might have to manually copy the contents of your plugin's `src/[platform]` folder into the correct place in the platform folder. for ios it would be `platforms/ios/[project name]/Plugins/[Plugin Name]`. on android it's something like `platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/[plugin name]`.

you don't have to do anything in config.xml, cordova does this automatically when you add a plugin via CLI. The only thing you might have to do manually is copying the native plugin files as I described above.

Comment: Hi thanks for helping...

I tryed to remove the plugin, install it again, check that is copied in the platforms/ios/[project name]/Plugins/ folder... but when I try to check connection in my app I get: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.connection.type')`. Any idea about this?

Comment: I checked out `platforms/ios/cordova/console.log`and i found this line: void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode. Does this help?

Comment: removing and re-installing the plugin usually doesn't help. what might help is removing and re-installing the entire platform. the plugin needs to be installed while you do that.

Comment: Damn myself... I find out that I'm including a wrong cordova.js file... don't know why...