# Phonegap 3.5 on iOS navigator.connection is undefined

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am porting an old Phonegap 2 app to Phonegap 3.5

I created a new project using the CLI. Added the core plugins, including network-information.

Then I copied my html, css and javascript files.

I am now using XCode to further develop the app.

The app starts on the ios simulator but gets stuck when calling navigator.connection in the code.

I checked that the plugin files are there at platforms/ios/[project name]/plugins/org.apache.cordova.network-information :

```
CDVConnection.h
CDVConnection.m 
CDVReachability.h
CDVReachability.m
```

The feature tag is there at the config.xml

I found this question [Cordova 3 - iOs - navigator.connection Undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475602/cordova-3-ios-navigator-connection-undefined) which is the more similar I found to what I am experiencing, but it has not helped me solve the issue.

What else can I check? I need this plugin working. The migration from old phonegap has been a nightmare so far.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by uninstalling the plugin, and installing it again. Even though everything looked ok, this solved the issue.